# Undefined when passing props to siblings reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

new to react and trying to passdown, props to components with react. but gets `undefined` result when receiving `{this.props.name}` in Track.js. And `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`
 when trying with `{this.props.track.name}` in Track.js render method.

It should render these tracks:

```
            tracks: [{
                name: 'Gold Slug',
                artist: 'DJ khaled',
                album: 'We da best',
                id: '102 sample ID'
            },
                {
                    name: 'Slim shady',
                    artist: 'Eminem',
                    album: 'Marshal materials',
                    id: '103 sample ID'
                }
```

Or this track:

```
        searchResults: [{
            name: 'You Mine',
            artist: 'DJ Khaled',
            album: 'I Changed a Lot',
            id: '101 sample ID'
        }],
```

Background info: Building an app that renders song tracks with name, artist and album. Also a search with search results and a playlist. I'm working with 6 components: App, PlayList, SearchBar, SearchResults, Track and TrackList.

App is a container. PlayList lets users adds Tracks to it. SearchResults displays results from SearchBar.

In App.js, I've set the state of searchResults in the constructor method and passed it down to  component.

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import SearchBar from '../SearchBar/SearchBar'
import SearchResults from "../SearchResults/SearchResults";
import Playlist from "../Playlist/Playlist";    

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            searchResults: [{
                name: 'You Mine',
                artist: 'DJ Khaled',
                album: 'I Changed a Lot',
                id: '101 sample ID'
            }],
            tracks: [{
                name: 'Gold Slug',
                artist: 'DJ khaled',
                album: 'We da best',
                id: '102 sample ID'
            },
                {
                    name: 'Slim shady',
                    artist: 'Eminem',
                    album: 'Marshal materials',
                    id: '103 sample ID'
                }
            ]
        };
    }

    render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Ja<span className="highlight">mmm</span>ing</h1>
            <div className="App">
                <SearchBar />
                <div className="App-playlist">
                    <SearchResults searchResults={this.state.searchResults}/>
                    <Playlist />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

SearchResults receives and .map iterates through the array and sets it to tracks within the TrackList component within render method.

SearchResults.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './SearchResults.css'
import TrackList from "../TrackList/TrackList";
import Track from "../Track/Track";

class SearchResults extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            //Adds a map method that renders a set of Track components on the tracks attribute.
            <div className="SearchResults">
                <h2>Results</h2>
                <TrackList tracks={this.props.searchResults.map(track => {
                    return <Track key={track.id} /> }
                )} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SearchResults;
```

TrackList.js renders a set of track components:

```
import React from 'react';
import './TrackList.css'
import Track from '../Track/Track'

class TrackList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (

            <div className="TrackList">
                <Track />
                <Track />
                <Track />
                <Track />
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default TrackList;
```

Track.js renders Tracks:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Track.css'

class Track extends React.Component {

    renderAction() {
        if (this.props.isRemoval == true) {
            return <h1>-</h1>;
        } else {
            return <h1>+</h1>;
        }
    }   

    //TODO: Fix rendering method on this.props.track.name
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Track">
                <div className="Track-information">
                    <h3>{this.props.name}</h3>
                    <p>{`${this.props.artist} | ${this.props.album}`}</p>
                </div>
                <a className="Track-action" isRemoval={true}></a>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Track;
```

Comment: You are not passing any props to the `<Track>` component

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you are not actually passing data down to the `Track` component.

```
class SearchResults extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            //Adds a map method that renders a set of Track components on the tracks attribute.
            <div className="SearchResults">
                <h2>Results</h2>
                <TrackList tracks={this.props.searchResults.map(track => {
                    return <Track key={track.id} /> }
                )} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Seems like `SearchResults` is trying to map thru the data is got via props, and render a `Track` for each one. Now if you look at this line right here, you will notice that no data is actually passed.

`return <Track key={track.id} /> }`

I think to fix your issue, all you would need to do is this.

```
class SearchResults extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            //Adds a map method that renders a set of Track components on the tracks attribute.
            <div className="SearchResults">
                <h2>Results</h2>
                <TrackList tracks={this.props.searchResults.map(track => {
                    return <Track key={track.id} track={track} /> }
                )} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Now in the `Track` component you can access `this.props.track.whatever`.